# What is the etymology of the word ketchup?

Tags: etymology

What is the etymology of the word *ketchup*? I've tried searching on Google without a definitive answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Supposed to be a maritime-related deal, with traders from the British East India company returning to the West from Malaysia bringing a recipe for something called kicap (pronounced: "kee-chap," with variable spellings and ingredients). Circa 17th cent. Of note is that the original was probably the same thing now available in Asian markets, called Nampla or Nuk-nam, a fermented fish sauce.

[Supporting link here.](http://books.google.com/books?id=KXaX4tUEOOsC&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=malaysia%20keechap&source=bl&ots=fZ6kHWHac4&sig=3emKIdZngM0fr6Bb0_9PI7GrSh4&hl=en&ei=r3HITaGxEeXr0QHCg_T_Bw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Also of interest is modern-day usage of both "catsup" and "ketchup."

Comment: Yeah, my family always says *catsup*.

Answer (score 7):

To supplement @The Raven's solid answer, I offer these:

- [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ketchup):

> **ketchup** 
>   1711, from Malay *kichap*, from Chinese (Amoy dialect) *koechiap* "brine of fish." *Catsup* (earlier *catchup*) is a failed attempt at Anglicization, still in use in U.S. Originally a fish sauce, early English recipes included among their ingredients mushrooms, walnuts, cucumbers, and oysters (Johnson, 1755, defines *catsup* as "A kind of pickle, made from mushrooms"). Modern form of the sauce began to emerge when U.S. seamen added tomatoes.

- An [Ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=catsup,%20ketchup&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) of catsup (blue line)
  vs. ketchup (red line).

[image: http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=catsup%2C+ketchup&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3]

- And a [quote](http://books.google.com/books?id=YkkhgGoE3_cC&printsec=frontcover&dq=the%20man%20who%20ate%20everything&hl=en&src=bmrr&ei=2Y3ITZ2PI5TUgQfE6fT-BQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&sqi=2&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Amoy&f=false) from Jeffrey Steingarten's excellent *The Man Who Ate Everything*:

> Where did ketchup get its start? The most popular theory is that the word itself defives from *kôe-chiap* or *ké-tsiap* in the Amoy dialect of China, where it meant the brine of pickled fish or shellfish. Some people prefer the Malaysian word *ketchap* (spelled *ketjap* by the Dutch), which may have come from the Chinese in the first place. In either case, sometime in the late seventeenth century, the name (and perhaps some samples and a recipe or two) arrived in England, where it first appeared in print as "catchup" in 1690 and then as "ketchup" in 1711, at least according to the *Oxford English Dictionary*. These exotic Asian names struck an evocative chord among the British, who quickly appropriated the names for their own pickled anchovies or oysters, long in popular use and probably descendants of the fishy, fermented Roman sauces, *garum* and *liquamen.*

Answer (score 2):

### Ketchup, OED, 1711

The OED says:

> Etymology:  apparently < Chinese (Amoy dialect) *kôechiap* or *kê-tsiap* brine of pickled fish or shell-fish (Douglas *Chinese Dict*. 46/1, 242/1). Malay *kēchap* (in Dutch spelling *ketjap*), which has been claimed as the original source (Scott *Malayan Wds. in English* 64–67), may be from Chinese.
>
> The Japanese *kitjap*, alleged in some recent dicts., is an impossible form for that language. (? error for *Javanese*.)

Their earliest quotation is 18th century:

> 1711   C. Lockyer *Acct. Trade India* 128   Soy comes in Tubbs from Jappan, and the best Ketchup from Tonquin; yet good of both sorts are made and sold very cheap in China.

But they have an earlier quotation for *catchup*:

> 1699   B. E. *New Dict. Canting Crew*,   Catchup, a high East-India Sauce.

### Ketchup, 1701

I found a 10-year antedating in *[The mysteries of opium reveal'd](http://books.google.com/books?id=XylFAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA350&dq=Ketchup%20OR%20Kitchup%20OR%20kee-chup&hl=en&sa=X&ei=e6YdUr_ZM-iG4gS-pYGoAw&ved=0CE0Q6AEwBQ)* by John Jones (1701) which uses it twice. First on page 350:

> [image: III The Vehicle in Vomiting should be small in Quantity pleasant comfortable and warming lest you should by either Quantity or Quality give any offence to the Stomach pleasing it answers the fame Intent with the Opiate k ielfj and has often good Effe8 without Opium for indeed every]
>
> [image: ifl ry leaser is proportionably an Opiate and Xypiiim is only sucfi in an intense ziA permanent wiwwirr therefore the Vehicle must be agreeable Sis yfortt Htffocr at or f1 e burnt with Spices liojimary &c or the best Cordials or wirh fame Ketchup Caviare dr Anchovts or a little a ic 6r dissolved in it upon the Fire acco d as the Person likes one or the other which tho sot used in common Praclic e are of rea t Benefit where they are pleasing and m liSefi of]
>
> III The *Vehicle* in *Vomiting* should be small in *Quantity*, pleasant, comfortable, and warming, lest you should by either *Quantity* or *Quality* give any offence to the Stomach; pleasing it answers the same *Intent* with the *Opiate* it self, and has often good *Effect* without *Opium* ; for, indeed, every *Pleaser* is proportionably an *Opiate*, and *Opium* is only such in an *intense* and permanent *manner*; therefore the *Vehicle* must be agreeable, as *Wine, Hippocras* or *Wine* burnt with *Spices*, *Rosemary, &c* or the best *Cordials*, or *Wine* with some ***Ketchup***, *Caviare*, or *Anchovis*, or a little *old Cheese* dissolved in it upon the Fire, according as the Person likes *one* or the *other*; which last (tho' not used in common *Practice*) are of very great *Benefit*, where they are pleasing and well liked of.

And page 358:

> [image: As to Diet, it must be Nourishing, Warming, Comforting, and Titillating, with realishing and high Sauces, Oisters, Anchovy, Caviare, Cockles, Ketchup, Mango's, Garlick, Onions, Leeks, Bear Garlick, Rocket, Sives, Shelot, Ginger, Aromaticks, Roots of Satyrion, Feaverfew, Goats-beard, Silver-weed, Skirrets, Parsnips, and Artichoaks.]
>
> As to *Diet*, it must be Nourishing, Warming, Comforting, and Titillating, with *realishing* and *high Sauces, Oisters, Anchovy, Caviare, Cockles, **Ketchup**, Mango's, Garlick, Onions, Leeks, Bear Garlick, Rocket, Sives, Shelot, Ginger, Aromaticks, Roots of Satyrion, Feaverfew, Goats-beard, Silver-weed, Skirrets, Parsnips,* and *Artichoaks*.

### Ketchup, 1708

A later antedating gives a hint of the content, in *[Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society of London](http://books.google.com/books?id=b8kwAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA2268&dq=Ketchup%20OR%20Kitchup%20OR%20kee-chup&hl=en&sa=X&ei=e6YdUr_ZM-iG4gS-pYGoAw&redir_esc=y#v=thumbnail&q=Ketchup%20%20OR%20Kitchup%20OR%20kee-chup&f=false)* (1708 - Volume 25 - Page 2268):

> [image: to the Hcrba Park Anisum Judicum to be the Sa Vessel of a sort of Fraxinella The Star os the Em so call d ma famous Receipt against the biting fiiad Dogs he proves to be the Coronoptts and not tl Sesamoides Salamanticum Magmtm which some mistake for Soia of which Ketchup is made is the Seed of Indian Phaseolus 5 as Angola Seeds are those of an Ah and Russia Seed of the Gramen Mann Salep Cijji muni ar and Dart tcort are 3 Roots the first of a sort Orchis the second of a Species of Galanga and the of an Indian Reed]
>
> *Soia*, of which ***Ketchup*** is made, is the Seed of: *Indian Phaseolus*; ...

Answer (score 0):

This is undocumented, but I heard that the term 'ketchup' originated with spice traders who travelled in Southeast Asia/ Hong Kong/ Canton province.  In Cantonese, the term 'chup' means literally 'sauce'.  In the provincial areas of Canton, tomatoes are called "Fan Ke".  In a slang phrase, Ke-Chup or Ket-Chup means tomato sauce.

Comment: Where did you hear this?

Comment: To follow up with Ron's comment as to Ke-Chup referring to "tomato"-"sauce", I can corroborate with local knowledge (unfortunately also undocumented). I am Malaysian of Chinese extraction and also speak Cantonese, for as long as I can remember my family members and friends have referred to this etymology being the case (along with other words in Malay, borrowed from Chinese dialects).

Comment: @E-LingL Trouble with that is that ketchup (as brought to Europe in the 17th century) _did not contain tomatoes_. It was fish-based. The ‘tomato sauce’ theory is a later folk etymology based on what ketchup is today. The 汁 _chɐp_ bit is right, but _ke-_ is 鲑, not 茄.

Answer (score -1):

#### Etymology:

First, the Amoy pronunciation of *鮭汁* is *kê-chiap*, meaning *salmonidae juice*.

Then, the pronunciation travels to Malaysia, and use the spelling *kechap*, and changes the meaning into *tomato sauce*.

Next, the pronunciation travels to the Netherlands, and spells as *ketchup*.

Finally, English use the *ketchup* spelling from Dutch.

Comment: The chronology is not quite right here. The meaning did not change to ‘tomato sauce’ until much later, after the word was borrowed into English. The Dutch form is _ketjap_, which is taken straight from Malaysian/Indonesian, where it’s one of the variants used (others include _kicap_ and _kecap_). The spelling _ketchup_ is uniquely English (until the word was borrowed far and wide from English, that is).

Answer (score -1):

Ketchup 果子汁is a Taiwanese word that means fruit juice. The name was brought back to Europe by the Dutch in the early 17th Century when Taiwan was a Dutch colony.

Along with ketchup, tea was brought back to Europe, the word "tea" came from Taiwanese.

- Taiwanese  *te*
- Dutch *thee*
- German *tee*
- French *the*
- Spanish *te*
- English *tea*